# Does the “O” in the google doodle for Olga Ladyzhenskaya have anything to do with her work?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-equations

Ladyzhenskaya is famous for fluid dynamics and partial differential equations, both of which are beyond my pay grade. And she worked on the Navier-Stokes equations. Does this [circle with the arrows](https://www.cnet.com/news/google-doodle-celebrates-mathematician-olga-ladyzhenskaya/) represent anything in particular?

All I know from differential equations is that they sometimes involve arrows in "direction fields", which may be a connection.

Answer (score 7):

The equation in the picture is the [Navier–Stokes momentum equation in convective form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Compressible_flow). The part inside the O looks  like a cross-section of (the velocity field of) a flow between two rotating cylinders, mentioned in Ladyzhenskaya's [Mathematical Analysis of Navier-Stokes Equations for Incompressible Liquids, 6.4](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/23fa/28319d928fa7d67eb72fde26bfa8e7c0611f.pdf), among other places, the so-called [Taylor-Couette flow (spiral vortex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%E2%80%93Couette_flow). But this is not something Ladyzhenskaya worked on specifically.

It is also similar to a picture of (the direction field of) an unstable spiral surrounded by a [limit cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle). Those appear in some finite-dimensional reductions of the Navier-Stokes equations (see e.g. [Wang Five-Mode System of the Navier-Stokes Equations on a Torus](https://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperInformation.aspx?PaperID=68842)), but this is even further from what she worked on. So it could just be a cute picture of a "fluid flow" that fits nicely into letter O.

[image: Ladyzhenskaya Google Doodle]